# Feature selection vs regulation in supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection

My question is why do we need to do feature selection even when have build in mechanics to prevent overfitting?
More specifically, for svm, it regulate the training use L2 norm, so that the model is "small" in a sense.
Why do we need another way to keep the model simple by using feature selection?